# Changing Values In An External Web Application Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I'm currently trying to get my web application to take data from a table and enter it into an external web application.  I was wondering if it was possible to do this with Javascript (without any external libraries e.g. jQuery, node, ect.).  So far all I have is:

```js
function otherWebsite(x){
    window.open('https://google.ie/','_blank');
}
```

So in that example I'd like to be able to get the id of the search bar and then enter the value x into it, then run the function to search that command on Google.  I'm aware that you're able to add data to the url for Google searches but I'm trying to do it without that.

Comment: Are both websites on the same domain? If so yes you can if you use window.postMessage

Comment: No sadly both websites are not on the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article on javascript.info on how to achieve cross-window communication. See this for a general overview about this topic:

> #### [javascript.info: Cross-window communication](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication)

And see also in detail:

> #### [MDN: Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
>
> *“The `window.postMessage()` method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.”*

Things getting much more complicated if the domains differ because of the security policy of browsers. Note the [security concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Security_concerns) on the MDN page about the postMessage method.

Comment: @Conor98 If that was helpful and you used this answer to solve your problem, it would be nice if you mark that answer as accepted. Of cause only if you want. It would not only help me but also others who have the same problem and come across this question while searching.

Comment: Hi Niklas I've just got around to going through it, sorry for the delay.  Its definitely a step in the right direction but I don't believe the website I'm trying to access has an event Listener so I don't think its possible to use this solution.  What I'm trying to do in essence is on the webpage I've created I have certain numerical values in a table.  On a button press I'm trying to open a new website not created by me or on the same domain that contains a calucator.  I want the values on my table to be automatically entered into this calcuator.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is not possible to force a page to provide data. It has to be made available to you consciously. This is the only way to protect data from thieves on the Internet. The intention can sadly not be filtered with software.